# Know all LDAP users in Gitlab

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, gitlab

Is there any command or any way to view all the users and their details (like CN, OU, DC) which are specified in LDAP settings in `Gitlab` or `Ubuntu terminal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAP would be used as a way of authenticating, but any LDAP user who might not have *yet* logged on to GitLab would not be reported: GitLab only creates users on their first connection.

Meaning: it is not because you have 2000 users who can authenticate through LDAP that GitLab would display 2000 users.

Regarding LDAP, only an **[`ldapsearch`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapsearch)** can list potential users:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://ad-your-server:<yourPort> -x \
 -D "<yourBindACcount>" -w <yourBindpassword> -b "DC=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=zz" \
 -s sub -a always -z 1000 \
  "(&(memberOf=CN=<aGRoup>,OU=aaa,OU=bbb,OU=...,DC=xxx,...)"
```

Regarding GitLab, check the [Rake task LDAP](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/raketasks/ldap.html):

```
# Omnibus installation
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check
```

> By default, the task will return a sample of 100 LDAP users. Change this limit by passing a number to the check task:

```
rake gitlab:ldap:check[50]
```

This is for checking only though: that would not list *all* users.